# Deleting Invisible Menu Item on WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to delete an invisible menu item. I'm not sure if I can do it or if I did do it, will it affect my other menu items? Thanks.

The website I'm editing is called. www.rannitv.com/magazine

[Screenshot of Menu Item I am Trying To Delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O471l.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.menu-item .menu-item-type-custom .menu-item-object-custom .menu-item-545 {display:none;}`

It should not affect your other menu items.